# Fast parallel traversal of directed acyclic graph with possible duplicate node visits allowed

Tags: java, multithreading, directed-acyclic-graphs

On a given datastructure representing a directed acyclic graph, a Set or Map can be used to keep track of the node-ids that have already been visited.

For the parallel case of multiple threads this Map needs to be synchronized e.g. by using the `ConcurrentHashMap`.

My algorithm gets a node of the graph from a list of nodes to process, it traverses all outgoing edges and adds the new nodes to that list for further sweeping through the graph unless they are found in the aforementioned Set of nodes which have already been visited.

In the parallel case N lists are used, one for each thread but all threads use the same Set to check if a node was already visited.

I want to avoid the synchronization overhead between the threads during 'look-up from' and 'add to' the set of visited nodes by allowing that multiple threads may sometimes visit the same node more than once. I assume that since each thread traverses the graph on its own path, the likelihood of two threads visiting the same node during a small timespan is low and a duplicate processing is acceptable for a few cases.

The above idea requires a technical solution that allows the following:
Whenever one thread adds a node-id to the set of visited nodes, another thread may see this change at a later time and **in favor of speed doesn't need to wait until another thread has finished** inserting the node-id into the data structure.

Using a regular unsynchronized HashMap is not an option since it may happen that concurrent insert/lookup operations see a temporarily inconsistent state which e.g. leads to an endless loop during lookup.

Can someone suggest how to write and read to such a data structure **without** using `synchronized` or other techniques of mutual exclusion **that block the other threads**?
I assume this can be achieved via atomic operations like compare-and-exchange or `volatile` that are used to actually implement thread-safety, but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is a "smart" object that doesn't just wrap a map with "synchronized" block. CHM handles reads and writes to specific buckets separately in the same way you describe. imagine a ReentrantReadWriteLock for each bucket. CHM does that for you and it is faster than Synchronized.

Comment: @TomElias thanks for this, especially that you pointed out the superior and efficient implementation of CHM. In the particular case that I tried to describe, I am interested whether it is possible and if so, - how - data can be safely 'inserted' into a data structure without using a blocking operation by e.g. only making use of atomic/special operations supported by the JVM. So each thread can write to the 'same' data structure in memory. I guess compare-and-exchange is needed if two write the same key, so I want to know how this is actually done in a correct way.

Comment: multiple writers are not usually supported for any multithreaded operation. if Thread1 and Thread2 both write to the same place in memory, what would you expect the final result be? you can't know and that makes for unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @TomElias 'Compare-and-exchange operations are often used as basic building blocks of lockfree data structures' from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange I think this gets me somewhere, just want to understand it and do something similar in Java.

Comment: some primitive types in java have the "atomic" wrappers, which use the compare-and-exchange method. for example AtomicInteger, AtomicBoolean etc'. in your case, you want to maintain a list of visited nodes and unfortunately implementation of the List interface do not support atomic operations. you would need to implement such a list yourself...